# Needs the clarity about async function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to get the value from setTimeout. but console gives no result. how to handle this `async` functions? can any one help me to understand this in right way?

here is my try:

```
async function getTheme() {
    const value = 'abc'
    setTimeout(() => {
        return value;
    }, 3000);
}

getTheme().then(time => console.log(time)); //getting no result.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because you're returning inside the `setTimeout` callback, which does not actually resolve the promise.

What you want is to instead return a promise instead:

```
function getTheme() {
    const value = 'abc'

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(value), 3000);
    })
}
```

There is no need to use `async`, since you are already returning a promise in the `getTheme()` function.

Of course, you can abstract the whole "waiting" logic into another function: then, you can keep the `async` if you wish:

```
function sleep(duration) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, duration));
}

async function getTheme() {
    const value = 'abc';

    await sleep(3000);

    return value;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to block whole of the code and make it linear while promise is in pending status?
e.g: ```console.log(getTheme(); // block for 3 secs console.log('after that 3 secs'); ``` ( I mean not in promise chain, just inline code )

Comment: Then you need to use `await getTheme();`. If you need access to the resolved data, then `const response = await getTheme();`

Comment: We don't (but it's [currently under proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await)), so you'll need to do that in /yet/ another async.

Comment: yep, But i can't understand why ```await``` not implemented in main thread. And what is the problem.